# Template class unable to work

Tags: php, class, templates, str-replace

I tried to fix my template class but it doesn't work,

what doesn't work was : the [@title]  doesn't get replaced.

Code:

```
protected $file;
protected $values=array();

public function __construct($file){
    $this->file = $file;
}

public function set($key, $value){
    $this->values[$key] = $value;
}

public function output() {
    if (!file_exists($this->file)) {
        return "Pagina kan niet gevonden worden.";
    }
    $output = file_get_contents($this->file);

    foreach ($this->values as $key => $value) {
        $tagToReplace = "[@$key]";
        $output = str_replace($tagToReplace, $value, $output);
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Hopefully someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `$tagToReplace`? Is it really `[@title]`? Secondly, what is the value of `$output`? What is the template file source code? According to the [file_get_contents](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) docs, it returns `false` on failure.

Comment: Yes, it is really [@title], because in another file I did this:

include('class/tpl.class.php');
$me = new Template("me.tpl");
$me->set("username", "brandon");
$me->set("title", "Test");
echo $me->output();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ is the start character for a php variable.
Simple escape it.

```
$tagToReplace = "[@\$key]";
$output = str_replace($tagToReplace, $value, $output);
```

//edit
I tested the code. On my test environment, all work fine.

```
$test = new Tpl(__DIR__."/test.txt");
$test->set("test", "huhu123");
$test->set("asdf", "xcv");
var_dump($test->output());
```

Testfile:

```
kjasdfgkashf [@test]
```

Output:

```
string(20) "kjasdfgkashf huhu123"
```

Comment: The `$key` needs to be interpreted, so escaping it won't solve the problem.

Comment: You're right, edited my answer and added a test case.

Comment: string(6038) "
This is what it gives me as output. What did I do wrong?

$test = new Template(__DIR__."/me.tpl");
$test->set("title", "huhu123");
$test->set("asdf", "xcv");
var_dump($test->output());
?>